# Any way to solve a system of coupled differential equations in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, enthought, sympy

I've been working with sympy and scipy, but can't find or figure out how to solve a system of coupled differential equations (non-linear, first-order).

So is there any way to solve coupled differential equations?

The equations are of the form:

```
V11'(s) = -12*v12(s)**2
v22'(s) = 12*v12(s)**2
v12'(s) = 6*v11(s)*v12(s) - 6*v12(s)*v22(s) - 36*v12(s)
```

with initial conditions for v11(s), v22(s), v12(s).

Comment: Take a look at [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).  It offers mathmatica-like functionality with python syntax.  It might be able to solve diff eqs.

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical solution, or a numerical solution?  (You mentioned using sympy, so you might be hoping for an analytical solution, if there is one.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser A numerical solution, similar to the NDsolve for mathematica.

Comment: It's first order, but this doesn't look like a linear system to me, as you have powers and products of the dependent variables.

Comment: @Bitrex You're right, I mistakenly wrote linear rather than non-linear. Post has been updated. Good catch!

Comment: I doubt this has a symbolic (analytic) solution, but even if it did, SymPy's dsolve doesn't yet support systems of ODEs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the numerical solution of ODEs with scipy, see [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html),  [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) or [scipy.integrate.ode](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).

Some examples are given in the [SciPy Cookbook](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/) (scroll down to the section on "Ordinary Differential Equations").

Comment: The documentation seemed a bit difficult to understand, but the Cookbook you linked fitted just perfect for what I was trying to do, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

In addition to SciPy methods `odeint` and `ode` that were already mentioned, it now has [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) which is newer and often more convenient. A complete example, encoding `[v11, v22, v12]` as an array `v`:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def rhs(s, v): 
    return [-12*v[2]**2, 12*v[2]**2, 6*v[0]*v[2] - 6*v[2]*v[1] - 36*v[2]]
res = solve_ivp(rhs, (0, 0.1), [2, 3, 4])
```

This solves the system on the interval `(0, 0.1)` with initial value `[2, 3, 4]`. The result has independent variable (s in your notation) as `res.t`:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.01410735,  0.03114023,  0.04650042,  0.06204205,
        0.07758368,  0.0931253 ,  0.1       ])
```

These values were chosen automatically. One can provide `t_eval` to have the solution evaluated at desired points: for example, `t_eval=np.linspace(0, 0.1)`.

The dependent variable (the function we are looking for) is in `res.y`:

```
array([[ 2.        ,  0.54560138,  0.2400736 ,  0.20555144,  0.2006393 ,
         0.19995753,  0.1998629 ,  0.1998538 ],
       [ 3.        ,  4.45439862,  4.7599264 ,  4.79444856,  4.7993607 ,
         4.80004247,  4.8001371 ,  4.8001462 ],
       [ 4.        ,  1.89500744,  0.65818761,  0.24868116,  0.09268216,
         0.0345318 ,  0.01286543,  0.00830872]])
```

With Matplotlib, this solution is plotted as `plt.plot(res.t, res.y.T)` (the plot would be smoother if I provided `t_eval` as mentioned).

[image: plot of solution]

Finally, if the system involved equations of order higher than 1, one would need to use [reduction to a 1st order system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_to_a_first-order_system).