# Solving integro-differential coupled system of equations with Python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use Python to numerically solve a system of equations described [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.1326.pdf), Eqs. 30 and 31, with a simplified form looking like:

[image]

where `G(k)` and `D(k)` are some known functions, independent of  `Y`. Of course, all quantities are functions of `t` as well. The authors comment that, due to the dependence exhibited by the various functions, a numerical solution is necessary.

I usually implement the solution to this type of coupled equations as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909779/any-way-to-solve-a-system-of-coupled-differential-equations-in-python) or [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/solving-coupled-differential-equations-in-python-2nd-order), for example, but now the extra k-dependence is confusing me a bit.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried, what issue have you encountered? Tell us more about this k coefficient and how it prevent you to solve this problem?

Comment: @jlandercy k is not a parameter but another variable; I have edited the question to show `S` explicitly. Honestly, I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Do you need to calculate `f(t)` and `Y(t)` at discrete values of `k` or over a given range?

Comment: @Patol75 ‘k’ is a continuous variable and it will be integrated over a certain range.

Comment: I assume we know `D(k)`, right? Does it depend on `Y`?

Comment: @Patol `D(k)` is know and it is Y-independent.

Comment: I think what I would do is discretise the range over which `k` is defined, say 100 values. Then, for each value of `k`, apply `solve_ivp` to the first equation. This will give you `f` continuous in `t` but discontinuous in `k`. Then, apply `solve_ivp` to the second equation and use Simpson formula (implemented in SciPy) to obtain `S`. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDESolver` is a general-purpose numerical integro-differential equation solver created by [Josh Karpel](https://github.com/JoshKarpel/idesolver). Its latest version allows the user to solve multidimensional, coupled IDEs. From the examples provided, an IDE like

[image]

with analytical solution (sin *x*, cos *x*), can be solved using the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from idesolver import IDESolver

solver = IDESolver(
            x=np.linspace(0, 7, 100),
            y_0=[0, 1],
            c=lambda x, y: [0.5 * (y[1] + 1), -0.5 * y[0]],
            d=lambda x: -0.5,
            f=lambda y: y,
            lower_bound=lambda x: 0,
            upper_bound=lambda x: x,
)

solver.solve()

fig = plt.figure(dpi = 600)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

exact = [np.sin(solver.x), np.cos(solver.x)]

ax.plot(solver.x, solver.y[1], label = 'IDESolver Solution', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 3)
ax.plot(solver.x, exact[1], label = 'Analytic Solution', linestyle = ':', linewidth = 3)

ax.legend(loc = 'best')
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title(f'Solution for Global Error Tolerance = {solver.global_error_tolerance}')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y(x)$')

plt.show()
```